# React Native Horizontal ScrollView does not fully scrolled

Tags: react-native

[image]

I have the above ScrollViews( highlighted in yellow color ) each one with maximum 6 items. When I try to scroll it to the end, I can't scroll 100%. Part of the last item will not view. See the following screenshot.

[image]

The highlighted red area is not able to see or scroll.

Following is the component,

```js
const Item = ({title, data}: any) => (
  <View style={styles.itemRoot}>
      <View style={styles.item}>
          <View style={styles.itemLeft}>
              {/* left inner container */}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.itemRightRoot}>
              <View style={styles.itemRightTitle}>
                  <Text>TITLE</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.itemRight}>
                  {/* area which render each ScrollViews */}
                  {title.items.map((item: any, index: number) => {
                      return (
                        <ScrollView horizontal>
                            {item.map((child, index) => {
                                return (
                                  <View
                                    key={index}
                                    style={{
                                        width: isTablet()
                                          ? (Dimensions.get('screen').width - 80) / 6
                                          : (Dimensions.get('screen').width - 64) / 3,
                                        marginRight: 8,
                                        marginBottom: 8,
                                    }}>
                                      <SectionInnerItem />
                                  </View>
                                );
                            })}
                        </ScrollView>
                      );
                  })}
              </View>
          </View>
      </View>
      {/* separator */}
      <View
        style={{
            height: 2,
            marginTop: 24,
            marginBottom: 24,
            backgroundColor: '#36363D',
            width: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 64,
        }}
      />
  </View>
);
```

And this is the stylesheet,

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    itemRoot: {
        marginLeft: 24,
        marginRight: 16,
    },
    item: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    itemRightRoot: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    itemRightTitle: {
        marginLeft: 24,
        marginRight: 16,
    },
    itemRight: {
        marginLeft: 24,
        marginRight: 16,
        paddingTop: 16,
        paddingBottom: 16,
    },
    itemLeft: {},
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, is there a way I can just use one single ScrollView but with a maximum of 6 items on each row and the rest of the items in the next row?

Comment: I tried your code but couldn't reproduce the issue. Everything's works fine.  I mean, the sixth item is fully visible on the screen when I scrolled.  So I guess the problem is  outside the "Item" component.

Comment: Maybe the bigger square on the left side of the screen?  But there is no style props in `itemLeft: {},`... so I can't debug further.

Comment: @Shin-00 Thanks for the comment, I did something and it seems like fixed the issue. What I did was, got the width of left Square ( say 200 ) and add it as the paddingRight: 200 for the ScrollView container. It seems fix the issue but it seems like a hack.

Comment: Good, then I got it. I'll write the answer below.

Comment: You don't have to  add `paddingRight: 200` for the  ScrollView container.

Comment: Just add `flex: 1` for the `itemRightRoot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Give `flex: 1` for the `itemRightRoot`.  The problem is that, `itemRightRoot` doesn't know the width of the rest of the screen with the square on the left side of the screen.

```
itemRightRoot: {
  flex: 1,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
```